# Atom editor opens to empty window and dev tools

Tags: atom-editor

I installed a buggy package in Atom which has been crashing the editor repeatedly.   So, I went into Atom Settings to remove it, but just out of curiousity I clicked the "Open Config Folder" button beforehand which opened an empty window and dev tools alongside:

[image]

Atom subsequently crashed (probably because of the buggy package I was about to install) and now when I open Atom, I only see the above window and nothing else, even if I open it from the "Open with Atom" context menu from any folder. So, now I'm stuck with just this window and no actual Atom Editor.

I tried re-installing Atom and it did not solve the issue.  I checked the "Atom" menu available in that window and it only gives me basic options: "Check for Update", "Reload", "Close Window", "Toggle Dev Tools", and "Quit", none of which can get me back to the main editor window.

Anybody seen this before or know how to break out of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a quick solution for this.  The Atom uses a BLOB file to store data from the last user session and re-open that when Atom is restarted.  By removing that file, Atom restarted at it's default state.

You can find that file on a Windows machine here:

```
C:\Users\[Username]\.atom\blob-store
```

Just delete, or rename, the file BLOB.  Then, just open up Atom and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 4):

[I got the same problem but on Ubuntu.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfzKA.png) I tried apt-get --reinstall and purge but both did not work.

Turns out it was just no read permissions for /home/username/.atom/

All I did to fix it was:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R '/home/username/.atom'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Close Atom
- Remove `C:\Users\[Username]\.atom\storage\application.json`
- Start Atom